# How to identify websites that give page not found error using HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

The following website loads but says "page not found".  Is there a test ("if" statement) that identifies this condition?

Ex:- Websites like this ...

http://www.vccircle.com/500/news/news-roundup-amrapali-raising-rs-80cr-from-icici-prudential

The code is as follows...i don't want the execution to stop on this error, it should just report it and continue with the execution.

```
        try
          {
            string s = w.DownloadString(TargetUrl);

            hd.LoadHtml(s);
          }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
```

I find that once try get the error the execution is going to catch and is blocking the whole application. i understand this must be a basic question related to exceptional handling, but i am learning...so please help.

Comment: **Never** write `throw e;`.  It destroys the stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `WebClient.DownloadString` to fetch the web page.
If it's not found, you'll get a `WebException`, and its `((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode` will be `HttpStatusCode.NotFound`

Comment: You should add a `catch(WebException ex)` block and check the `StatusCode`.

Comment: and then should will the control return to the point where the function was called?

Comment: If you don't throw an exception, the code after the `catch` block will execute.